# Tranfers data between two columns in eav_attribute table

Tags: magento-1.7, eav

I need a help to do a data transfer between two columns in customer eav_attribute. I have a field called "rg" with some data, I need to transfer this data to the "taxvat" column, but I don't know how I can do this.

Like this...

```
+-------------+               +-------------+
|  rg         |               | taxvat      |
+-------------+               +-------------+
| 066111...   | Transfer      | 066111...   |
+-------------+ ------------> +-------------+
| 022111...   |               | 022111...   |
+-------------+               +-------------+
| 044111...   |               | 044111...   |
+-------------+               +-------------+
```

The "rg" column I won't use anymore, but I need these data inside the "taxvat" column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it by using simple SQL query (for flat table):

```
UPDATE `table_name` SET `taxvat` = `rg`
```

And if there is EAV structure, you need to use following query (assuming that both values are in `customer_entity_varchar`. If not use another table instead):

```
   UPDATE `customer_entity_varchar` tr
  JOIN `eav_attribute` eav
    ON tr.attribute_id = eav.attribute_id AND tr.entity_type_id = eav.entity_type_id AND eav.attribute_code = 'taxvat'
SET tr.value = (
  SELECT value
  FROM (
         SELECT
           src.value,
           src.entity_id
         FROM `customer_entity_varchar` src
           JOIN `eav_attribute` eav_s
             ON src.attribute_id = eav_s.attribute_id AND src.entity_type_id = eav_s.entity_type_id AND
                eav_s.attribute_code = 'rg'
       ) AS t
  WHERE t.entity_id = tr.entity_id
)
```

Comment: This would work if it was a flat table. But it doesn't work for EAV attributes since they are not columns in a specific table.

Comment: I've added the SQL for EAV structure

Comment: I think this attribute is for customers, not products. At least that's what I understood from the question.

Comment: Doesn't matter. Just change `catalog_product_entity_varchar` for whatever table you need